# How to set compilation option in many projects

Tags: c#, .net, stylecop, csproj

I have many projects/solution in my company. I want to simple them configuration.

How can I assure every project to have checked "Treat warnings as errors", it is possible? Or force all project to use one styleCop file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually change all project to [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) some shared set of settings (usually named with ".target" extension) to set `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` for all projects. If doing so check if setting on project level does not override import one.

Sample from article:

```
</Project>
  ....
  <Import Project="$(CommonLocation)\General.targets" />
</Project>
```